# A dynamic 2d char array

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

I have a question about the C code for a dynamic 2d char array: malloc buffer overflow. The program idea is to initialize a global 2d char array, when the program is running, type some words, and save them into that 2d char array. I'm not familiar with the realloc function.  What is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
char **array_history;
int count = 0;
#define MAX_LINE_CHARS 1024
int main (void){

    array_history =  malloc(sizeof(char *));
    while (1) {
        char line[MAX_LINE_CHARS];
        if (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_CHARS, stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        array_history = realloc(array_history, sizeof(char*)*(count + 1));
        int len_size = strlen(line) + 1;

        array_history[count] = malloc(len_size*sizeof(char));
        for (int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            array_history[count][i] = line[i];
            // printf("%c", line[i]);
        }
        // printf("%s", array_history[0]);
        // for (int i = 0; history[i] != NULL; i++) {
        //     printf("%s\n", history[i]);
        // }
        count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; array_history[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s", array_history[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array_history[i] != NULL` Where do you think this sentinel `NULL` would come from? Memory you get via `malloc` or `realloc` are not required to be initialized. It's up to you. You also do not have any memory for that `NULL` value. You only allocate memory for the lines you read in.

Comment: for (int i = 0; array_history[i] != NULL; i++), this step i want to  print the array_history

Comment: I know but why do you think there would be an array element holding a `NULL` pointer? If there is no such array element your code will happily walk through all memory it can get hands on and access locations it is not allowed to.

Comment: Also: You should never use this pattern:  `array_history = realloc(array_history, ...`. If there is an error `realloc` will return `NULL` and you have no more access to the memory location you had before. This includes no way to free that memory. Always use some temp variable and check for `NULL` before assigning to the pointer you passed into `realloc`.

Comment: You also fail to terminate your strings: `for (int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++)` This will not copy the `0` byte. Why don't you just use `strcpy` or `strdup` or similar for this purpose?

Comment: I used the 'strcpy' before, but it also failed to print the array_histroy.

Comment: Sure. strcpy does not solve the missing `NULL` pointer. It only fixes the missing string termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code.
You fail to terminate your strings and you fail to add the sentinel value that you are using when printing your string.

A fixed version could look like this:
(You should add more error checking for malloc etc.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE_CHARS 1024

int main (void){

    char **array_history;
    int count = 0;
    array_history = malloc(sizeof(char *)*(count+1));
    // TODO: Check for NULL
    array_history[0] = NULL;  // Terminate the array.

    while (1) {
        char line[MAX_LINE_CHARS];
        if (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_CHARS, stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        void *temp_ptr = realloc(array_history, sizeof(char*)*(count + 2));
        // TODO: Check for NULL
        array_history = temp_ptr;

        int len_size = strlen(line) + 1;
        array_history[count] = malloc(len_size*sizeof(char));
        array_history[count + 1] = NULL;  // Add sentinel for your array

        int i;
        for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            array_history[count][i] = line[i];
            // printf("%c", line[i]);
        }
        array_history[count][i]=0; // Terminate the new string.
        // Or simply use strcpy(array_history[count],line);
        
        // printf("%s", array_history[0]);
        // for (int i = 0; history[i] != NULL; i++) {
        //     printf("%s\n", history[i]);
        // }
        count++;
    }

    // Instead of terminating NULL value you could just use condition `i<count`
    for (int i = 0; array_history[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s", array_history[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I understand what you mean, I forgot the NULL also needs to occupy.

Comment: It's not only about occupying memory but also about assigning `NULL` to the last array element.